# Directory.exists not working with aspnet.friendlyURL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, global

i installed new ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update for microsoft.aspnet.friendly.urls [LINK](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx). and it is working as promised, my all new new and old web pages are now friendly. my project is asp.net 4 webform iis7

I am facing a problem with

> Directory.exists

. i am using this code to get the folder exists or not. this code is in Global.asax file under Application_BeginRequest section.

```
If Directory.Exists("~/users") Then
        Response.Write("hello")
    End If
```

it is not working or not going in the if condition. it tried **("users"), ("/users"), ("/users/")** but no one working. it is a syntax error, but i am not able to get

**Edit:**

```
If Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/users/" & parameters(i))) Then
                Dim originalPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower()
                If originalPath.Contains(parameters(i)) Then
                    Context.RewritePath("/users/" & parameters(i) & "/default.aspx")
                End If
            Else
                Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/error.aspx"))
                Return
            End If
```

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?

Comment: Brain, problem is solved with "rs" server.mappath method. my users folder is on root /. thank you for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map URL to server folder path, try this

```
Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/users"))
```

Comment: hello rs, i am using your example it is working for folder but not working for file(~/error.aspx), i edited the main post for full code.

Comment: @JasbirBhinder, remove Server.MapPath from response.redirect, you use this function only to find folder and files and with Request/Rsponse methods